# How to change the color of a pixel in an image

Tags: c#, colors

I read a single pixel out of an image using the following code:

```
private void CheckArea(Point where)
{
    Bitmap test = (Bitmap)PanelToBitmap(panel2);
    var pixel = test.GetPixel(where.X, where.Y);
}
```

I want to change the color of this pixel. First I tried to convert it into an image but that doesn't work. Then I tried to change the ARGB-values, but they are write-protected.

How can I change the color of a pixel in an image given a `Point`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use :

```
test.SetPixel(where.X, where.Y, Color.FromArgb(0x78FF0000));
```

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.setpixel.aspx)

Color is an immutable structure, so you can't change its values.